# JQuery autocomplete change event not being fired

Tags: jquery, search, input, autocomplete

I am trying to conditionally change a link URL whenever someone enters a value in a JQuery autocomplete search field, however, using the following code I cannot for some reason either register the change event or even bind a handler:

```
 $("#protocol-name").autocomplete({
    source: protocol_names,
}).bind( "autocompletechange", function(){
    alterURL();
 }).focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
    $(this).autocomplete('search');
});
```

Additionally, $("#procotol-name").change() registers nothing either, where protocol-name represents an input field.

Comment: Does it work when you supply it as an init option? `change: function(event, ui) { ... }

Answer (score 5):

Try to do like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: excellent, that worked. it's strange how the other methods of doing this didn't though...

Answer (score 2):

In fact `change` event is fired, but only after input element has lost its focus. You can [check it](http://jsfiddle.net/nashbridges/LS2CY/1/) yourself.

UPD: this behaviour is inconsistent across browsers, see http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8878

Comment: Is not fired in Chrome versions 23, 24.

Comment: steps to see it is not fired: 1) fill "ap". 2) press "down arrow" key. 3) Now in input field you see "apple", press "tab", not fired...

Comment: @nigi ah, I see. I was not testing actual autocompletion :) Updated the answer.